# Equation of a plane that crosses the axes at points equidistant from the origin.

Tags: vector-spaces, plane-curves

Give the equation of a plane that crosses the axes at points equidistant from the origin. Explain your reasoning.

I know the equation should be on a 45 degree angle looking towards the axis. I have the picture in my head, but I don't know.

Comment: Is this just in $\mathbb R^3$ or arbitrary dimension?

Comment: This is in R3 dimension.

Comment: So you basically need a plane passing through $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: Maybe something like $x+y+z=1$.

Comment: Exactly, that was exactly what I was thinking. But how do I add (1,0,0), (0,1,0) and (0,0,1) in an equation

Comment: You don't add them in the equation (the statement "add them in an equation" doesn't make a lot of sense in English actually).  Instead, you just check that they satisfy the equation when substituted in.  In other words $x=1, y=0, z=0$ satisfies the equation and so do the other two points.

Comment: x+y+z=1 works perfectly. It is from a Canadian High school. I just copy pasted the question.

Comment: Ah those wacky Canadians, lol

Answer (score 2):

Your plane does not pass thorough the origin , so itd equation is of the form:
$$
ax+by+cz=1
$$
Now the point where this plane intercept the axis are:

for $(y,z)=(0,0) \rightarrow x= \dfrac{1}{a}$

for $(x,z)=(0,0) \rightarrow y= \dfrac{1}{b}$

for $(x,y)=(0,0) \rightarrow z= \dfrac{1}{c}$

since you want $\dfrac{1}{a}=\dfrac{1}{b}=\dfrac{1}{c}=k$ (the same distance)

the searched equation is: $x+y+z=k$

Comment: Exactly, thank you my man.

Comment: Not to knock your very good answer, but strictly speaking the plane could pass through the origin.  Then the distance from the origin is zero for all axes which is equidistant.

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to accept if you want

Comment: @ Gregory: OH YES! Special case forgotten!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $x+y+z=1$.  Check that it is a plane and passes through $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ which are all the same distance (one) from the origin.